# Match alphanumeric string with length six chars using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex for validating alphanumeric String with length of 6 chars. I tried with following regex And done it for allowing alphanumeric chars but don't know how to stop exceeding more than six chars.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b]+$");
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/gjxz1ze3/1/).

Comment: the `{number}` quantifier: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\b]{6}$`

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}$");`

Comment: `{1,6}` is 1 *to* 6 so any length < 7 would be valid

Comment: @AlexK. _dont know __how to stop exceeding more than six chars.___

Comment: Above solutions are not working .It allows more than six characters in the input field.

Comment: What's the reason fot that `\b`? Inside a character group it's nothing but an escaped b, which is already included in `a-z`

Comment: @htoniv: Please provide a fiddle with non-working code. How are you using the regex? I guess `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,6}$/` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fiddle link here  https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/gjxz1ze3/1/

Comment: As I thought. You only check one character against the whole regex.

Comment: What if you just use `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}">`?

Comment: Same result is coming

Comment: Read any basic regexp tutorial or documentation. Or google for "javascript regexp limit n chars". Also, why are you not simply using a regexp literal?

Comment: I attached my fiddle link. can u make this workable. https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/gjxz1ze3/2/. @torazaburo

Comment: I raised a similar question (no uppercase support), https://stackoverflow.com/q/76370865/10655742, the question was answered by using the boundery flag `\b` so you need `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\b`

Answer (score 2):

you just have to add `{6}` in the end

`var regex = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9\b]{6}$');` You can test it out here [https://regex101.com/](http://regex101)